# Create NI TestStand Sequence file from Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, teststand

I have a Microsoft Excel file which have two columns and sixteen rows of Data. As image attached.

[Excel Reference Image to import sequence data to NI TestStand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7BNm.png)

Please I need help to Import excel data to NI TestStand sequence file. This excel file for just reference only.

Please let me know if there is any confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the data you are referring to in the Excel file properties? Or did you want to actually create Test Steps from Excel file?

If it's properties to load, then use the Property Loader Step. To make it easier, you can do an export which will create the XML layout which you can modify the data with the one in the Excel.

As far as creating a Test Step based on Excel file, that's not how TestStand works.

Comment: Actually i want to create test steps of 300 sequences.

Comment: refer to this example. this may help you with that. [link](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Building-a-Sequence-Using-the-TestStand-API/ta-p/3527244)

Comment: pinguu i didn't have access to this location. please suggest another example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Import Properties](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019RPoSAM&l=en-US).

I would first create a test sequence as a model and export the properties from it. Then you can use that as a template to import the properties you have in your excel file.

From what I see from your example though.  It may be easier to just manually create the sequences and steps, if that's all there is.  If you have to create 300 steps or sequences it may be a better idea to utilize loops or create a [module](https://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-TestStand/Need-to-access-TestStand-Sequence-Step-Parameters-from-Excel/td-p/143324).